# Is there a way to combine incrementing and decrementing for loops?

Tags: java, for-loop, space-efficiency

```
int j = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
{
  if ((columnIndex + i) > 6 || this.isWinningCondition(columnIndex, i, j, colSlot, isRed))
     {
         break;
     }
  else
     {
        pieces++;
     }
}
for (int i = -1; i > -4; i--)
  {
    if ((columnIndex + i) < 0 || this.isWinningCondition(columnIndex, i, j, colSlot, isRed))
    {
      break;
    }
    else
    {
       pieces++;
    }
}
```

Basically, it is apart of a Connect4 program that searches for three in a row on the left and right side of a specific column (in this case, it is searching for horizontal wins), hence the incrementing (for the right side) and the decrementing (for the left side) for loops. Is there a way I can combine these for loops into one, so I don't have to repeat myself?

Comment: Could you provide an example and format your code according to Java coding conventions to make your question more clear?

Comment: `for (int i = -3; i < 4; i++)` ... you just have to slightly change your range check to make sure the tested index is inside the legal range and that i is not 0.

Comment: @Nitram there are different conditions in these two `if`s

Comment: @SashaSalauyou The only thing "different" is the range check that is optimized in the template to the searching approach direction. You can easily extend it to check both directions and get the same effect.

Comment: @Nitram `(columnIndex + i) > 6` and `(columnIndex + i) < 0`--they are different, I cannot see how 6 and 0 are related to ranges.

Answer (score 0):

If your *MaxValue* ( 4 )is always the same for both for loop, you can always do :

```
for( int i = 1; i < 4; ++i)
{
   //verify i version 1
   int i2 = i * -1;
   // verify i2 version 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the mixed for loop.

```
for(int i = 0, j = 4; i <= 4 && j >=0; i ++, j --)
{
 System.out.println(i + " " + j);
}

Output:
0 4
1 3
2 2
3 1
4 0
```